# OSDev: Windows 7 'copy' command won't copy to b:\ from ImDisk

Tags: build, osdev, dd

I have a .bat (Batch) file compiling an OS I am making in Windows 7. I use nasm to compile the code, then dd and imdisk. Although probably not worth mentioning, after compilation I use mkisofs to make a .iso then VirtualBox for testing.

When it gets past "Copying kernel and files to disk" it (the output in the prompt) says `The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted. 0 file(s) copied.`

It compiled before in which I could properly test the OS and some text would appear, then I noticed nothing appeared on the screen anymore, so I further looked at the prompt output and batch file and realized this.

Can anyone give me some help here? I really want it to compile.

Here is the main part that errors in my batch file:

```
echo Adding boot to disk
cd build
dd if=..\src\boot\boot.bin bs=512 of=myos.flp
cd ..

echo Mounting disk image
imdisk -a -f build\myos.flp -s 1440K -m B:

echo Copying kernel and files to disk
copy src\kernel.bin b:\

echo Dismounting disk image
imdisk -D -m B:
```

I am able to successfully compile MikeOS (my inspiration) with pretty much the same commands (I modified the MikeOS buildwin.bat to use dd), so I have no idea what is happening.

EDIT: I even tried this in Ubuntu with dd and it doesn't work! When I get to the mount part it says something about the filesystem...I think my dd command is wrong, but for some reason I can compile MikeOS correctly. Ugh.

Comment: Ugh...it still won't work. I redid the script (same commands, but I mean redid everything in a new directory, etc.) and it still says the same annoying "0 file(s) copied." I wish I could figure it out. When I modified MikeOS' build script to use dd, it worked perfectly!

Comment: `dd if=..\src\boot\boot.bin bs=512 of=myos.flp` will truncate the entire image file after writing the boot sector. If you originally created and formatted it, that `dd` command just wrote a boot sector and the rest of the file is gone. You might want to ensure that after you create the original disk image (and format it) that you write the bootsector without truncation. I'd recommend this `dd` command for that `dd if=..\src\boot\boot.bin bs=512 of=myos.flp conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 0):

The boot file should always be in the first sector. Try this:

```
dd seek=0 if=..\src\boot\boot.bin bs=512 of=myos.flp
```

seek=0 copies the boot file to the first sector. If you don't put it, the dd command may copy the file to somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It's been a while, but I found out way later on that the reason it never worked was because the "boot.bin" that I was trying to put on the floppy drive didn't have the necessary header info.